# GROUP BY clause is not working in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, group-by

```
SELECT 
    place.PlaceID, place.Location, place.PlaceName, place_img.ImgPath 
FROM 
    place 
LEFT JOIN 
    place_img ON place.PlaceID = place_img.PLACE_PlaceID 
GROUP BY 
    place_img.PLACE_PlaceID
```

The above SQL query works fine if I used it without the `GROUP BY` clause. I don't understand what the problem is with the `GROUP BY` clause.

If I run the query without using `GROUP BY` clause:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISyEa.png)

But if I run the query with the `GROUP BY` clause, then I get:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBY3j.png)

Why is this happening?

Comment: The bigger question is why do you think you need `GROUP BY` here in the first place.  `GROUP BY` is mainly useful if you want to take aggregates (e.g. sums, averages) over _groups_ of records.  If you are already happy with the first version of your query, then there is no need to spruce it up by adding `GROUP BY`.

Comment: actually there are 2 tables named as `place` and `place_img`. there are more than 1 record in `place_img` table for one PlaceID (PlaceID is the primary key on `place` table and it's the foreign key of the `place_img` table). I need to select only one image from the `place_img` table for each record in the `place` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really just one image path per place, and you don't mind which path you get, then you may try this:

```
SELECT
    p.PlaceID,
    p.Location,
    p.PlaceName,
    MAX(pi.ImgPath) AS ImgPath
FROM place p
LEFT JOIN place_img pi
    ON p.PlaceID = pi.PLACE_PlaceID
GROUP BY
    p.PlaceID,
    p.Location,
    p.PlaceName;
```

Note that if `place.PlaceID` be the primary key of that table, then you may simplify the `GROUP BY` clause to the following:

```
GROUP BY p.PlaceID
```

Comment: Also I have another question please. This same database and same table with same data are in another machine. If I run the SQL Quary in there it work fine and return the same data set as I needed. May I know why?

Comment: @A.Madhushani A speculation, but one possibility is that the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` modes are different between the two MySQL servers.  Depending on the mode, your current `GROUP BY` query might return the same as my answer, or it might not even run at all.  The bottom line is that you should write proper code; my answer is one possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use GROUP BY like this, because you did not specify what to do with the aggregated data.

Your group by should be in form of:

```
SELECT AGGRATION_FUNCTION(FIELD_1), FIELD_2
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY Country;
```

This way, the SGDB know what to do with field_1 when he has to agregate data

Example of how to use GROUP BY : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

If you are not sure what to do with the aggregated data, it might be because you are not really wanting to use a GROUP BY or you are not selecting the right field.